# Magento 2 SKU and URL Key is not generating unique by default

Tags: magento2, url, sku, duplicate

When I create multiple product with same **SKU** and same **URL Key** it is creating, as I know Magento do not allow this.

I googled alot but didn't find any configuration for this,

Please guide me what is the issue?

> Is Magento Stop creating unique url's and sku in 2.3 version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed this extension and followed their instruction and it solved my issue:
https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites